# Logging into Office365 Exchange via Powershell, from scratch

Tags: windows, email, powershell, office365, exchange

I've tried to do so from a plain, newly installed powershell with nothing else installed on top, but the official way simply seems to lead to errors about missing package managers, not-existing package providers, missing commands, and various other similar messages. (The microsoft site simply states `Install-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement` is all that is needed)

Simply put, the real way to do so is to install a whole mess of interdependent programs into powershell to finally be able to run the `Install-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement` command. The instructions on doing so are fragmented all over the Microsoft site, and trying to do so involves debugging a dozen or so different errors, which is a time-consuming process.

What is a **complete** set of steps to go from a plain powershell to one that can connect to the Office-365 Exchange Online, on a Windows machine?

---

Comment: Hi, i'm here to confirm the progress of your thread, is there any update? If your problem has been fixed, you could mark the best answer or share your solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Available modules and cmdlets are PowerShell version-specific. You are not saying, what WinOS you are running, nor which version of PowerShell you are running.

***There is no reason to install PowerShell on Windows***. ***It is there by default***, as it is part of the OS. Just use the start menu to fire either the console host or the ISE (integrated scripting environment). However, if you are on legacy Windows, then you are on legacy PowerShell unless you upgraded the Windows Powershell version to the latest.

[Differences between PowerShell versions](https://4sysops.com/wiki/differences-between-powershell-versions/#:%7E:text=PowerShell%20and%20Windows%20versions%20%5E%20%20%20PowerShell,R2%20SP1%20...%20%204%20more%20rows)

So, powershell.exe or powershell_ise.exe are the executables.

***The only other option for install is to install a cross-platform PowerShell Core*** (though not required for what you are after, but it is a choice and you can use either, even at the same time.)

***Installing PSCore does not upgrade or replace Windows PowerShell***, which is part of the OS. It's a side-by-Side model and...

```
pwsh.exe
```

... is the executable for PSCore.

Then you update, the PowerShell help files...

```
Update-Help -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

..., and then use the...

```
Find-Module
```

... command alone to update package management or a specific module,

```
Find-Module -Name 'ExchangeOnlineManagement' | 
Install-Module -Force
```

... or just run this...

```
Install-Module -Name PackageManagement -Force -MinimumVersion 1.4.6 -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber
```

... manually, to update the package manager.

Lastly, install the modules you need/want, and have them autoloaded by using your PowerShell profile. In your profile, this...

```
# Required for use with web SSL sites
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::
SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
```

... should be in there as well as in all your scripts that are distributed.

To use anything on O365/M365, you must login to the service first.

> Connect to all Microsoft 365 services in a single PowerShell window
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/connect-to-all-microsoft-365-services-in-a-single-windows-powershell-window?view=o365-worldwide

```
$orgName="<for example, litwareinc for litwareinc.onmicrosoft.com>"
$acctName="<UPN of the account, such as belindan@litwareinc.onmicrosoft.com>"
$credential = Get-Credential -UserName $acctName -Message "Type the account's password."

#Azure Active Directory
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $credential

#SharePoint Online
Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -DisableNameChecking
Connect-SPOService -Url https://$orgName-admin.sharepoint.com -credential $credential

#Skype for Business Online
Import-Module MicrosoftTeams
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $credential

#Exchange Online
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Connect-ExchangeOnline -ShowProgress $true

#Security & Compliance Center
Connect-IPPSSession -UserPrincipalName $acctName

#Teams
Import-Module MicrosoftTeams
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $credential
```

Answer (score 0):

Through some trial and error, I've managed to do it this way (Although I'm not exactly sure how safe and correct it is to do so, or if there are some redundant steps, as the proper knowledge is fragmented):

To Start:

First is to check the powershell version with `Get-Host`, which has to be at least `5.0`. If not, install the latest `.msu` package for it by downloading and running said installer. Then run:

```
# Powershell defaults to TLS1.1, which was deprecated. 
# Thus by default its package management functions ship broken. Force it to use TLS1.2 by setting:
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Find-PackageProvider -Name "NuGet" -AllVersions
# Select the latest version
Install-PackageProvider -Name "NuGet" -RequiredVersion "2.8.5.208" -Force
# Check with 
Get-PackageProvider
# Register the repo 
Register-PSRepository -Default -Verbose
# Check with 
Get-PSRepository
# Check which version pops up in the error when running 
Install-Module PowerShellGet
# Then run the command to update PowerShellGet (replace the version number with the latest from the previous command): 
Install-Module PowerShellGet -RequiredVersion 2.2.5
# Finally: 
Install-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
# Next, enable running scripts with: 
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
# Import
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
```

Comment: The only thing you really need to do is first set TLS to 1.2, then install-module ExchangeOnlineManagement will already work. So `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` `Install-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement` is all that is really needed.

Comment: @LPChip That would just result in `Import-Module : The specified module 'ExchangeOnlineManagement' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory` (because there are no directories, repositories, etc. by default).

Comment: Ah forgot the `install-module ExchangeOnlineManagement` one. That one is also required.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your windows server/client version is the **supported operating system**, and your server/client meets the **prerequisites for the EXO V2 module**(**[Supported operating systems for the EXO V2 module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#install-and-maintain-the-exo-v2-module)**):

[image]

Then install the EXO V2 module:

1. Install or update the **[PowerShellGet module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/installing-psget?view=powershell-7.1)**(Ensure you are using TLS 1.2)
2. Install the EXO V2 module with the command **`Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement`**

Except using EXO V2 module in PowerShell to manage office 365 objects, you could also use the **[basic auth to connect to Exchange Online PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/basic-auth-connect-to-exo-powershell?view=exchange-ps)**(Before that, the **[prerequisites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/basic-auth-connect-to-exo-powershell?view=exchange-ps#what-do-you-need-to-know-before-you-begin)** should be noticed.)